# Не правильно скрывается элемент

Tags: jquery, javascript

есть код http://jsfiddle.net/sHmfA/
по идее, когда курсор уходит мимо div'а, элемент скрывается, но бывают случаи когда это происходит не корректно работает, элемент не скрывается, в чем беда?

Comment: hover это не mousein

Answer (score 1):

как-то так если оставаться в той-же разметке.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var $likes = $('#likes'),
         $headerlikes = $('.headerlikes'),
         time;
     $likes.hover(function () {
         clearTimeout(time);
         $headerlikes.finish().fadeIn(500);
         $likes.css('color', 'rgb(232, 57, 114)');
     }, function () {
         time = setTimeout(hidethem, 100); //это чтобы дырку пропустить между элементами.
     });

     $headerlikes.hover(function () {
         clearTimeout(time);
         $headerlikes.finish().fadeIn(500);
         $likes.css('color', 'rgb(232, 57, 114)');
     }, hidethem);

     function hidethem() {
         $headerlikes.finish().fadeOut(500);
         $likes.css('color', 'rgb(153, 153, 153)');

     }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/sHmfA/3/

Answer (score 0):

Вы спрашиваете про метод stop?
http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: не, там другая проблема, наведите на ссылку, а потом уйдите за фрейм и не попадая в появившийся блок вернитесь к документу. как-то так.

Comment: я уже по коду, вашим комментариям и ответам понимаю, о чём идёт речь, какой глюк должен наблюдаться (обычно такое при переключении в другое окно по cmd+tab ещё бывает), но почему-то не вижу этой проблемы. А вот мельтешение есть вовсю.

Comment: ну вообще говоря, тут сильно не изменишь (у меня тоже немного промигивает), я пробовал делать stop() и там проявлялся другой глюк, думаю лучшим выходом было-бы css transitions и переключение классов.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял, что при наведении на `#likes`, вы заставляете `.headerlikes` появится, а при триггере `mouseleave` Вы хотите, чтобы `.headerlikes` изчез, я ведь правильно понял? Однако, если Вы проходите мимо блока, этот код не срабатывает, не срабатывает он лишь по той причине, что триггеру `mouseleave` требуется, чтобы перед ним был задействован триггер `mouseenter`. Согласитесь, нелогично "уходить" оттуда, где Вы не были. [Прочитайте больше](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) про `mouseleave` и посмотрите на пример в самом конце страницы, он как раз это показывает.